# AFNetworking 2.0 iOS 7 Copy with zone warning in AFHTTPRequestOperation.h file

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5, afnetworking-2

In AFNetworking 2.x version for Xcode 5, I am Continuously Receiving the warning for this Method for this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithRequest:self.request];
```

the `self.request` is Incompatible pointer types sending `'NSURLRequest *'` to parameter of type `'MKLocalSearchRequest *'`

```
#pragma mark - NSCopying

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithRequest:self.request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [self.responseSerializer copyWithZone:zone];
    operation.completionQueue = self.completionQueue;
    operation.completionGroup = self.completionGroup;

    return operation;
}
```

is anybody get Solved this issue(warning) ..

Comment: There's a related recently opened issue on this topic here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[self class]` returns a `Class` object of a type that is not determined. The compiler is matching the `-initWithRequest:` method with that from MapKit. This can be fixed by changing the code to:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithRequest:self.request];
```

Comment: Great Neal its Solved the issue by Typecasting .. i was thought of that but i am New in AFNetworking so its better ask for the suggestion..